# Azure Data Factory Data Flows - Transforming values from JSON arrays

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a generic pipeline using a Data Flow and column patterns to convert an incoming datetime to a timestamp. The datetime is formatted as an array of integers representing the time when the message was received, as shown with an example below.

```json
{
  "messageID": "b48c3c7c-1491-da18-e932-d23a014cab62",
  "receiveDate": [2021, 5, 23, 4, 43, 59, 546777701]
}
```

The "datetime array" should be converted to a timestamp, which in this case would be `2021-05-23 04:43:59.547` as Data Factory does not accept more than three digits in the milliseconds.

**First solution attempt**

My first attempt looked something like the following, where I just wanted to examine if I could retrieve the year from the incoming array and avoid some unnecessary string manipulation.

```
Matching condition: endsWith(name, 'Date') && type == 'array'
Column name expression: $$
Value expression: $$[1]
```

Unfortunately, the above syntax is not valid as the `$$` is not recognized as an array even though the type is explicitly set as an array in the matching condition. I also tried to use `array($$)[1]` but that just wraps the entire array in another array and not the individual values.

**Second solution attempt**

At this point I was content with using string manipulation to achieve the desired result, so I tried to retrieve the year by using the following value expression.

```
Value expression: split(substring(toString($$), 2, length(toString($$)) - 2), ',')[1]
```

Inspecting the output confirmed the leading and trailing square brackets were removed before the split operation, but again it failed to retrieve the year and no changes were made to the `receiveDate` field. If I remove the `[1]` the result is `["2021", "5", "23", "4", "43", "59", "546777701"]` as expected, so apparently the indexation into the splitted array is the problem.

**More information**

I also tried importing the schema projection and use the same string manipulation syntax, but with a direct reference to the `receiveDate` field instead of using the `$$`. The settings (which includes the `[1]` indexing into the array) and the output from the debug session is shown below.

[image]

To my surprise the debugger shows the correct year, even though the split-operation (without retrieving the first element) produces the exact same result in both cases, including the types.

If I could solve the problem outlined above, I would produce the timestamp by performing a cumbersome series of operations, such as the following:

```
toTimestamp(
    split(substring(toString($$), 2, length(toString($$)) - 2), ',')[1] + '-' + /* Year */
    iif(
        toInteger(split(substring(toString($$), 2, length(toString($$)) - 2), ',')[2]) < 10, 
        '0' + split(substring(toString($$), 2, length(toString($$)) - 2), ',')[2], 
        split(substring(toString($$), 2, length(toString($$)) - 2), ',')[2]
    ) + '-' + /* Month */
    /* Same pattern with the Day, Hour, Minute, Second and Milisecond. */
)
```

I would appreciate any feedback or alternative solutions. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your solution is right. If we were you, we also use expression to make up the data string. That the way to deal with the string.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way would be this in the derived tx. There is an even more concise way of converting to timestamp. Unfortunately there is a bug in the product that causes this to error out. Until that is fixed you have to continue to use string manipulation.
(Snippet of the DSL script)

```
each(match(endsWith(name, 'Date') && type == 'integer[]'),
      $$ = toTimestamp(toString(($$ ? integer[])[1]) + '-' +
                       toString(($$ ? integer[])[2]) + '-' +
                       toString(($$ ? integer[])[3]) + ' ' +
                       toString(($$ ? integer[])[4]) + ':' +
                       toString(($$ ? integer[])[5]) + ':' +
                       toString(($$ ? integer[])[6]) + '.' +
                       toString(($$ ? integer[])[7]/1000000),
                       'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'
                      )
                 )
```